# Bit Mutation of Genetic algorithm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a data which is like that, say, b= [['00000001', '00000010', '00000011'], ['00000011', '00000100', '00000101']]. I want to mutate or flip some items on list based on certain probability. After mutation, say 1st item on list, say b[0][0] become '10000001'. I tried this way .

```
    b=[['00000001', '00000010', '00000011'], ['00000011', '00000100', '00000101']]
from random import random, sample, choice
def mutation(x, mutation_rate):    ## Mutation function define
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x[0])):
            if random() < mutation_rate:           #### Make mutation based on certain probability
                x[i][j] = type(x[i][j])(not x[i][j])  ## This portion flip [0 to 1 or 1 to 0]

    return x

c=mutation(b, .05)
```

There is no error massage but mutation function make no change when mutation_rate .05 but when mutation_rate is .5 result is like that: c=mutation(b, .5)  ## calling function 
[['00000001', 'False', 'False'], ['False', 'False', '00000101']]

Comment: `p` is an integer. It's impossible to iterate over an integer. You probably meant to iterate over the elements of `b`.

Comment: Yes. I find what i did wrong. After correction, there is no error but mutation make no change.

Comment: Yes. I want to iterate over the elements. - ForceBru

Comment: First thing first. `x[i][j]` is a _string_ that consists of more than one element. So, you aren't flipping any bits here. Also, these aren't bits, they're _strings_, so doing `not 'any string'` doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

`x` is a list of lists of strings. Hence, `x[i]` is a list of strings. Hence, `x[i][j]` is a string.

Then:

```
type(x[i][j]) == str
(not x[i][j]) == (not bool(x[i][j])) == (not True) == False
=> type(x[i][j])(not x[i][j]) == str(False) == 'False'
```

This is why you're getting a lot of `'False'`s in your output. These ones and zeros aren't bits, they're *strings*.

Answer (score 0):

change to this

```
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(x[0])):
        for bit in len(x[i][j])
            if random() < mutation_rate:           #### Make mutation based on certain probability
                x[i][j][bit] = '1' if x[i][j][bit] == '0' else '1'  ## This portion flip [0 to 1 or 1 to 0]
```

this iterate to each bit and change if probable

Comment: You can't assign to individual characters in a Python string. This code would work if the strings were replaced by lists of single characters, but not without that.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figure it out. I made some modification based on your suggestions and made this change.

```
from random import random, sample, choice
def mutation(x, mutation_rate):
    for i in range(len(x)):
        for j in range(len(x[0])):
            p=[]
            if random() < mutation_rate:  #### Make mutation based on certain probability#
                for bit in range(len(x[i][j])):
                    m=x[i][j][bit]
                    p.append(m)
                p[0] = '1' if p[0] == '0' else '1'
                b=p[0] + p[1] + p[2] + p[3] + p[4] + p[5] + p[6] + p[7]
                x[i][j]=b
    return x
```

> b=[['00000001', '00000010', '00000011'], ['00000011', '00000100',
>   '00000101']]
>
> c=mutation(b, .5)
>
> result : [['00000001', '10000010', '10000011'], ['00000011',
>   '00000100', '00000101']]

So bit modified.

Thanks for help and suggestions.